# Unable to install libjsonrpccpp-dev and other dependencies on Linux Mint 21.2

Tags: linux-mint, apt, apt-get

I cant install install libjsonrpccpp-dev on Linux Mint 21.2.
I did `sudo apt update` first.

```
$ sudo apt install -y libjsonrpccpp-dev
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libjsonrpccpp-client0 libjsonrpccpp-server0
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-doc libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev libssh2-1-dev libjsonrpccpp-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libjsonrpccpp-client0 libjsonrpccpp-dev libjsonrpccpp-server0
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 386 kB/534 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,492 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-openssl-dev amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.10
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-openssl-dev amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I get a similar output if i try to install the suggested packages.

The commands `sudo apt --fix-missing install`, `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt update` afterwards resulted with the same output.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/710884/1049683